# Mikrotik Ovpn with RADIUS

Tags: openvpn, radius, mikrotik

I need to setup OpenVPN server on a Mikrotik router. The authentication for the clients needs to be done by a Windows RADIUS server.

My problem is that the Mikrotik uses the unencryptrd PAP protocol to comunicate with the RADIUS server when authenticating on behalf of the Ovpn server. It works but is insecure. Meanwhile, for the L2TP server the Mikrotik uses encrypted protocols.

I enabled the PAP on the RADIUS server and it works. Sure, I can create a VPN between the server and the Mikrotik to secure the communication. I want to find out if there is a way to force the Mikrotik to use a secure protocol for the Ovpn as it does for the L2TP?

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use `MS-CHAPv2` instead of `PAP`.

Go to the `"PPP"` section and click on `"Profiles"`. Edit the profile. change the `"Authentication"` setting to `"MSCHAP2"`. On the Windows RADIUS server, make sure that `MS-CHAPv2` is enabled.

Comment: I don't see the "Authentication" option in the profile. I have "PPP Authentication&Accounting" in the "Secrets" section, but I can't choose a protocol from there.